# Angular 2 let user choose and image from their local machine

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm very new to Angular. I'm trying to make a simple web application using Angular 2 where I allow the users to select and image from their local computer. Then I want to display this image in an `<img>` tag. Later perform actions on the image like rotate, change scale, change width...etc.

This is what I have in my component

```javascript
@Component({
    selector: 'image-container',
    template: `
        <input type="file" (change)="changeListner($event)" />
        <img id="image"/>
    `,
    directives: [ImageActionsComponent]
})
export class ImageContainerComponent { 
   // make FileReader work with Angular2
   changeListner(event){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloaded = function (e) {
            // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
            var src = e.target.result;
            document.getElementById("image").src = src;
        };

        // read the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. How do I read an image and update the src attribute using Angular2?

I'm just trying to learn Angular. :)

Is there a better and easier way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34230492/5043867 have a look here....this may help you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have `onloaded` event name. There is no such event, it should be `onload`:

```javascript
import {Component, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'image-container',
    template: `
        <input type="file" (change)="changeListner($event)" />
        <img class="image" />
    `,
    directives: [ImageActionsComponent]
})
export class ImageContainerComponent {
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

    changeListner(event) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var image = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.image');

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var src = e.target.result;
            image.src = src;
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Also it's better to use `ElementRef` to locate image within a component.

Comment: i tried it in angular 4 but it says property result doesnot exists on type EventTarget

Comment: @AnilShrestha sounds like some TS typing problem

Comment: var src = e.target.result; this line is causing error. it says the .result doesnot exists

Answer (score 2):

For those who faced this error with angular: property result does not exists on type EventTarget

you can work around it simply by:

```
this.url = event.target['result']
```

Answer (score 1):

As this answer states [How to preview picture stored in the fake path in Angular 2/Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074806/how-to-preview-picture-stored-in-the-fake-path-in-angular-2-typescript) to avoid property 'result' does not exist on type 'eventtarget' 
 you can also determine the type of e to be any as the following:

```
reader.onload = function(e: any) {
        var src = e.target.result;
        image.src = src;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this:

```
reader.onload = (e) => {
   image.src=reader.result;
}
```