# How to preview picture stored in the fake path in Angular 2/Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, image-uploading

Browsers don't take full path of local disc, instead they concatenate the filename with fakepath. Is there any way to access the file (image) from fakepath using typescript or angular 2?

I have this:

```
<img src="{{path}}" />
```

where my path variable stores the 'fakepath':"C:\fakepath\pic.jpg" in my .ts file.

**Edit**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422066/how-to-preview-picture-stored-in-the-fake-path) question discusses the way to preview image file from fakepath using javascript. If it is possible with Js, then is it not the same in case of ts?

Comment: I don't get the problem. How is this Angular or typescript related?

Comment: The question you linked has no accepted answer. Also, the other questions talks about *uploading* a file and showing the path from where it was uploaded. DO you also have an uploaded file or do you want to show the file directly form your local disc?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
<input type='file' (change)="readUrl($event)">
<img [src]="url">
```

```
readUrl(event:any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
      this.url = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly fine. Can you please explain what's happening in the code. You see I am new to Javascript and typescript and these syntax of the code is bit overwhelming.

Comment: Glad to hear. Learned something new. Never heard of fake path before.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This doesn't work, I don't know if its release versions. I am on Angular 2.3.1 and it errors out on this line: this.url = event.target.result; And when I add console log inside the reader.onload method,  I get: {
    "isTrusted": true
}

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Perhaps worth a new question with more details.

Comment: @user875139 Changing `reader.onload = (event)` to `reader.onload = (event:any)` work for me. It's seems like it's an issue with Angular reader interface.

Comment: I see. That's some compiler setting AFAIK. I use TS only in Plunker where these type annotations don't matter. For real development I use only Dart and don't know these TS details.

Comment: I am getting error. property " URL"does not exists on mBaseReader.

Comment: @KunvarSingh please create a new question with your code

Comment: @HasmukhBaldaniya thanks for the improvement. I don't get what value the comment adds though.

Comment: You are welcome @GünterZöchbauer. but 'Event' type doesn't work. Please Replace with 'any'

Comment: do some changes here 

**`event:Event => (event:any)`**

 & `reader.onload = (event:any)` also in angular 4

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: What about multiple file upload?

Comment: @baj9032 then you'll need to iterate over all entries in `event.target.files` instead of just the first one `event.target.files[0]`

Answer (score 10):

Adding to @GünterZöchbauer answer, this wasn't working for me until I added this:

```
reader.onload = function(e:any){
   this.url = e.target.result;
}
```

Prior to adding 'any', I was getting the error:

```
property 'result' does not exist on type 'eventtarget'
```

Comment: Quite unlikely this code will work. `function(e:any){` should be `(e:any) => {` otherwise `this` won't point to the class containing the code (which is quite likely what you want).

Answer (score 4):

It works when you change the event to type of any. In that way, Angular can access any of its property.

```
readUrl(event) {
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (event:any) => {
    this.url = event.target.result;
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

It's working

example.component.html

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" required />
<img [src]="imageShow" height="200"> <br/>
```

example.component.ts

```
imageShow: any= '';
onFileChanged(event) {
  this.file = event.target.files[0]
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  reader.onload = (event) => {
   this.imageShow = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
 }
```

}