# Get picture with relative path

Tags: image, angular, local

I create an Angular 4 application. I would like to get a picture that is on my computer (not good but temporary) and call with a relative path.

```
this.avatar = 'C:/Users/....../images/picture.png';


<img [src]="avatar" class="user-img"/>
```

But I have a security problem, do know why and what can I do ?

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: have you tried `/images/picture.png` ?

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='file' (change)="readUrl($event)">
<img [src]="url">
```

In your component:

```
readUrl(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.url = event.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

From: [How to preview picture stored in the fake path in Angular 2/Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074806/how-to-preview-picture-stored-in-the-fake-path-in-angular-2-typescript)